# Округление в запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Возникает ошибка при выполнение некоторых запросов с большими числами.
К примеру, в скрипт передается число 1376758470793**0700**, в запросе оно логирутся как 1.3767584707931E+16 и при запросе к бд преобразуется уже в 1376758470793**1000**(вычитается из ....0700 ....1000 и получается ошибка.столбец UNSIGNED (тип если важно то bigint(20)).
Данные цифры это кол-во кораблей в игре если что.

Comment: Что значит "в запросе логируется как 1.3767584707931E+16" ? Оно в таком виде подставлено прямо в тексте MySQL запроса ? попробуйте вносить его как текст, пусть MySQL сам преобразует его в число. У меня ощущение, что у вас php не понимает 64 битные числа и делает из них float. Посмотрите как скомпилирован PHP https://stackoverflow.com/a/864402/5669174

Comment: php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'
9223372036854775807

Как тогда этот запрос переделать под строку?
 UPDATE planets SET hunter = hunter - 1.0325688530948E+16 WHERE id = 1;

Comment: А каким образом тогда это число с +16 попадает сейчас в строку запроса. проверьте в каком виде оно содержится в переменной php. Если оно там не искажено, то используйте подготавиливаемые выражения и привязку значений http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-bind-param.php (т.е. запрос должен выглядеть как `update ... set hunter=hunter - ? where id=?` и к нему осуществляться привязка значений 13767584707930700 и 1 через bind (или передаваться в виде массива в execute, если вы используете PDO)

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/84ceb5783d6b291b7f92a56c9ff54b4ffd4efc6d
Вот код обработчик числа(стока 446 отправляет запрос)
там выше закоментирован код который и сохранял запрос в файл и там был Е+
вот код надстройки над mysqli http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68bbbd6ac79ea8082dcb8974c0b704cd21ad5fe8

Comment: Этот код ничего не даст. контрольный пример https://ideone.com/H9FBar показывает, что такое большое число должно спокойно вставляться в текст. значит у вас с ним происходит что то странное где то ранее. ищите место где теряется точность. А вообще всю работу с БД надо переписывать, переводить на подготавливаемые запросы. подстановка в текст делает выполнение запросов более медленным и потенциально приводит к разнообразным проблемам вроде неожиданных результатов и sql-инъекций

Answer (score 1):

В коде была конвертация в дробное число,отсюда и пошли все ошибки